# We couldn't finish installing updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

After installing updates and rebooting, I am getting message

"We couldn't finish installing updates"

[image]

If I click to this message, I get to "Windows Update" section of "UPDATE & SECURITY" with no further information (saying device is up to date).

If press check for update, it finds

[image]

starts to download it at everything repeat.

**UPDATE**

I looked `Event Viewer`, got error code from there and the following procedure helped: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821

Comment: share the folder **C:\windows\logs\CBS**